# How to "one tap and hold in order to drag" in Windows 10 with a touchpad

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, scrolling, scrollbar

I have an ACER laptop with Windows 10 and I've been struggling with one frustrating setting that I cannot change.

I use a touchpad for my work. In order to drag and move a scrollbar, I need to point the cursor over it and then double tap on it (holding the second tap).

I would like to be able to just single-tap (holding the second tap) on a scrollbar in order to move it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just single tap and move is the same as just moving the mouse without holding anything, how do you want to release the scroll bar then?

Comment: So I used PC/Mac back and forth and I had to get use to this double tap (hold) and use my other finger to drag/drop.  Vs Mac which is just a single tap (hold) and the other finger to drag/drop.  For just general scrolling; the Acer Predator I just got seems to support two finger scrolling, but it definitely doesn't feel like OS X.  IE feels better than Chrome, which makes me wonder what's going on from a Graphics Acceleration standpoint.  I'm still looking for a single tap option so I don't get confused in my day to day.

Answer (score 1):

While both the mouse and touchpad are used for moving a pointer around a screen, these two are completely different devices with their own strengths and weaknesses (even when a PCs touchpad isn't as powerful as a Mac's with its multitude of multi-touch gestures). Instead of trying to apply mouse working patterns to your work with touchpad I would suggest you to try leveraging capabilities unique to touchpad to achieve desired outcome (i.e. scrolling a page).

Configuring one or two-finger scrolling might free you from your frustration so you would not have to interact with scrollbars any more.

[image: touchpad scrolling configuration]

Assuming that your touchpad is made by Synaptics you can access these settings by clicking **Additional mouse options** under *Settings* → *Devices* → *Mouse and touchpad* → *Related settings*.

[image: mouse and touchpad options]

Comment: If you give maybe a short blurb about why the requested feature isn't desired such as @Máté Juhász's comment, I think your answer would be in tip-top shape.  Otherwise, it seems like you're ignoring the question.

Comment: @benJephunneh I can see your point. I've added short explanation.